# new_version package returns null flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i tried to show a dialog box to users if in case a newer version is released.I have used new_version package version : 0.3.0. But im recieving a warning.[image]

```
  void _checkVersion()async{
  final newVersion=NewVersion(
  final status=await newVersion.getVersionStatus();
  if(status?.canUpdate==true){
    newVersion.showUpdateDialog(
  context: context,
  versionStatus: status!,
  allowDismissal: false,
  dialogTitle: "UPDATE",
      dialogText: "Please update the app from ${status.localVersion} to ${status.storeVersion}",
);}}
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code snippet?

Comment: Yes, Code please and the name of the package

Comment: updated, package name : new_version (https://pub.dev/packages?q=new_version)

Comment: {FIXED} I found how to fix the problem. I was using the "new_version" package and I changed to "new_version_plus" and the bug is no longer there!

PS: add this: if(status?.localVersion != status?.storeVersion) { newVersion.showUpdateDialog(

Answer (score 6):

Anyone who still faces this issue can try a new package [new_version_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version_plus), you can use the same code by just changing the name, it works completely fine.

Comment: Confirming, works good as for Android as for Ios. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the package name as value in androidId key if working on android to let the new Version function check and compare .Below is the Updated code

```
 void _checkVersion()async{
    final newVersion=NewVersion(
      androidId: "com.snapchat.android",
    );
    final status=await newVersion.getVersionStatus();
    if(status?.canUpdate==true){
      newVersion.showUpdateDialog(
        context: context,
        versionStatus: status!,
        allowDismissal: false,
        dialogTitle: "UPDATE",
        dialogText: "Please update the app from ${status.localVersion} to ${status.storeVersion}",
      );}}
```

Comment: {FIXED} I found how to fix the problem. I was using the "new_version" package and I changed to "new_version_plus" and the bug is no longer there!

PS: add this: if(status?.localVersion != status?.storeVersion) { newVersion.showUpdateDialog(

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not forgetting to mention "Release Note" while uploading aab to google play console. when NewVersion is unable to find release note it returns null

Answer (score 0):

{FIXED} I found how to fix the problem. I was using the "new_version" package and I changed to "new_version_plus" and the bug is no longer there!

PS: add this: if(status?.localVersion != status?.storeVersion) { newVersion.showUpdateDialog(